# jqueryui - need to specify image tag within a span in a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, image

Using jQueryUI. When users click on the delete_comment_button image, I want a dialog to appear that allows users to delete their comment.

The challenge: the image falls within a span (all the other dialogs on my site work fine). How do I specify an image within a span in the selector?

Code below; jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRVBz/1/

**HTML**

```
<span class="delete_comment_button"><img src="delete-button.png"></span>

<div id="delete_comment_dialog" title="Alert">
Are you sure you want to delete this comment?
</div>​
```

​**jQuery**

```
  $(function(){

    $( "#delete_comment_dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
            }
    });
  });


    $('.delete_comment_button img span').click(function() { 
            $('#delete_comment_dialog').dialog('open'); 
            return false; 
    });
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have your selector around the wrong way. The `img` is within the `span`, so use:

```
$('span.delete_comment_button img').click(function() { 
        $('#delete_comment_dialog').dialog('open'); 
        return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. For some reason, it's not working/firing. When I click on the image, nothing happens.

Comment: I forked and fixed your jsFiddle, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnTfP/1/). Your click binding code was also incorrectly outside the `$(function() { ... });`.